# Infinite irreducible polynomial over Q[x] using Eisenstein

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, rational-numbers

Like the title describes, I know that over Q for each number n ≥ 1, one can easily construct infinitely many irreducible polynomials of degree n. But I want to prove using Eisenstein's criterion this fact: specifically, **for each n ≥ 1, exists infinitely many irreducible polynomials of degree n over Q[x]**. I am using the following definition of the criterion:

> Let $F(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$ be a polynomial with coefficients in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers. Suppose that there exists a prime number $p$ such that
>
> - $a_n$ is not divisible by $p$,
> - $a_i$ is divisble by $p$ for $0 \leq i \leq n-1$,
> - $a_0$ is not divisible by $p^2$
>
> then $F(x)$ is irreducible over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is certainly possible ... what are you finding difficult about carrying out this plan? (When you say "an infinite irreducible polynomial", do you mean "infinitely many irreducible polynomials"?)

Comment: Please do not use images.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, sorry I mean "infinitely many irreducible polynomials". I need clues to start the problem, I was suggested to do it by the Eisenstein criterion but I don't get how.

Comment: @Nkm20 Start by writing down *one* polynomial of degree $n$ which is irreducible by Eisenstein's. Then see how you can tweak it so that the coefficients change but the conditions for irreducibility remain satisfied.

Comment: There are infinitely many primes.

Comment: @Nkm20, write one  polynomial which is irreducible with respect a prime $p$, by Eisenstein criteria. Now change the prime $p$ with another prime $p'$ and according adjust the coefficients in order to satisfy Eisenstein. The process is applicable for infinitely many primes, giving you infinitely many irreducible polynomial of certain degree

Comment: Seconding Arturo, I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't). In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Consider $x^n+p$ for primes $p$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots\}\subset\mathbb Z$ be the set of all prime numbers. For each $i\in\mathbb N$, define

$$F_i(x):=x^n+p_ix^{n-1}+p_ix^{n-2}+\ldots+p_ix^2+p_ix+p_i$$

Clearly, each $F_i(x)$ is unique. A simple test of Eisenstein's Criterion shows that $F_i(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$.